# Winforms comboBox databinding whole object (no dataMember)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I've got difficulties binding a simple object to a comboBox as follow :

```
public partial class Planning : Form
{
    private static BindingList<VisiteVisiteur> visiteurs = new BindingList<VisiteVisiteur>(Program.model.VisiteVisiteur.ToList());
    public VisiteVisiteur visiteur = visiteurs.Last();

    public Planning()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = visiteurs;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", visiteur, "", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

I want to bind to whole **visiteur** object so it updates as the comboBox **selectedValue** changes.
At the moment, the selectedValue changes but not the visiteur object. What am I doing wrong here ?

**SOLUTION :**
Use the SelectedIndexChanged event to update the **visiteur** variable

```
public partial class Planning : Form
{
    private static BindingList<VisiteVisiteur> visiteurs = new BindingList<VisiteVisiteur>(Program.model.VisiteVisiteur.ToList());
    public VisiteVisiteur visiteur = null;

    public Planning()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        VisiteVisiteur visiteurTemp = visiteurs.Last();

        comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        comboBox1.DataSource = visiteurs;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = visiteurTemp;
    }

    public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        visiteur = (VisiteVisiteur)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Comment: Change to `comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", this, "visiteur", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`

Comment: I already tried and got this error : _Cannot bind to the property or column visiteur on the Data Source created from Object._

Comment: The currently accepted answer is totally wrong. Make your `visiteur` **property**, then use @Fabio code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer of Crowcoder will set `visiteur` to `comboBox1.SelectedItem` only once.   That is why you need to use manually updating by `SelectedIndexChanged`

You can do proper databinding (thanks to comment of Ivan Stoev) if you change member `visiteur` to a property

```
public VisiteVisiteur visiteur { get; set; }
```

Then set databinding

```
comboBox1.DataSource = visiteurs;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", 
                           this, 
                           "visiteur", 
                           true, 
                           DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

And if you still stay with manual updating of `visiteur` then use `SelectionChangesCommitted` event instead of `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DataSource` already sets the binding. You don't want to add another, you want to set the `SelectedItem` which is the object instance:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = visiteurs;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox1.SelectedItem = visiteur;
```

Comment: Your code only does half of the work because I want **visiteur** to automatically change its value to the comboBox selectedValue

Comment: @Nerimah, `visiteur` IS the value. what do you mean?

Comment: No, visiteur is the variable that is bound to the combobox value and it needs to take the value of the comboBox1.selectedValue

Comment: @Nerimah, I don't think you understand how comboboxes work. If I understand you, all you need to do in the selectedindexchanged event of the combobox is set `visiteur = combobox1.SelectedItem;`

Comment: That's correct but I would like to know if it's possible to do what you said with bindings only

Comment: @Nerimah, you would have to add a binding to `visiteur`, not the combobox. But `VisiteVisiteur` would have to inherit from `Control` and that's a mess. WPF is more appropriate for rich databinding than winforms.

Comment: Alright thanks for your advice. Anyway I managed to make it work with `SelectedIndexChanged` event plus a temporary variable because this event is fired 2 times in my case : first when the comboBox1.DataSource is set, then when comboBox1.SelectedItem is set

Comment: @Nerimah, it is better for future Googlers if the correct answer is marked as correct. Consider un-accepting mine.